# SQL job failed to run a C#.net console application with an status message: 403

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint, console-application, csom

I have a console application that uses credential to connect Share Point Online from "Windows credential manager" and request Share Point Online to download all items from list and further this information is used to start the procedure on the SQL Server

I'm not experienced in writing such application, but particular this application works normally when it executes from Visual Studio or by executing file. But it fails with error code 403 when it executes by SQL Agent on the same computer.

For clarification: SQL Server runs on the same computer where I develop the application and where is Share Point credential is stored.
I start job under my windows account using proxy, so I suppose there is no problem with credential. My windows account has sysadmin permissions on the SQL Server and admin persmissions on the OS.
But after searching for whole day I have no idea where the mistake could be.

Please help me with advice and tell me where I made a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

There is output error from SQL Job:

```
Message
Executed as user: LAPTOP\username. Unhandled Exception:System.Net.WebException: 
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.     
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()     
at SharePointTrigger.Program.GetNewItem(String targetSiteUrl, String listName, 
String filedName) in 
C:\Work\Korus\Pernod\Vista\Repose\ETL_LoadDataCSV\SharePointTrigger\Program.cs:line 114     
at SharePointTrigger.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
C:\Work\Korus\Pernod\Vista\Repose\ETL_LoadDataCSV\SharePointTrigger\Program.cs:line 40.  
Process Exit Code -532462766.  The step failed.
```

And there is console application (there is no App.config file and DatabaseOperation class. However DatabaseOperation class contains only method for executing procedure on the SQL Server):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using static SharePointTrigger.DatabaseOperation;

namespace SharePointTrigger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //To get values from App.config
            string SQLServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SQLServerName");
            string SQLDatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SQLDatabaseName");
            string SQLProcedureName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SQLProcedureName");
            string SQLJobName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SQLJobName");
            string SPSiteURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SPSiteURL");
            string SPListName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SPListName");
            string SPStatusColumnName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SPStatusColumnName");
            string SPLoadIdColumnName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SPLoadIdColumnName");
            string SSISVariable_name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSISVariable_name");
            string SSISEnvironment_name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSISEnvironment_name");
            string SSISFolder_name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SSISFolder_name");

            int itemCounter = 0;

            JobResult jobResult = new JobResult();

            List<MyItem> myItemList = GetNewItem(SPSiteURL, SPListName, SPStatusColumnName);           
            
            myItemList.Sort((x, y) => y.id.CompareTo(x.id));

            if (myItemList.Count() > 0)
            {
                //To avoid reload the same items
                foreach (MyItem item in myItemList)
                {
                    List<FieldValue> fieldValueList = new List<FieldValue>();

                    fieldValueList.Add(new FieldValue() { fieldName = SPStatusColumnName, fieldValue = "In progress" });

                    UpdateListItem(SPSiteURL, SPListName, item.id, fieldValueList);
                }
                
                //To start jon
                MyItem myItem = myItemList[0];
                int SPListId = myItem.id;

                SqlConnection sqlconnection = DatabaseOperation.GetSqlConnection(SQLServerName, SQLDatabaseName);
                jobResult = DatabaseOperation.StartSQLJob(sqlconnection, SQLProcedureName, SQLJobName, SSISVariable_name, SSISEnvironment_name, SSISFolder_name, SPListId);
            }

            //Update items fields Status, Loadid
            itemCounter = 0;

            foreach (MyItem myItem in myItemList)
            {
                if (itemCounter == 0)
                {
                    List<FieldValue> fieldValueList = new List<FieldValue>();

                    fieldValueList.Add(new FieldValue() { fieldName = SPStatusColumnName, fieldValue = jobResult.result });
                    fieldValueList.Add(new FieldValue() { fieldName = SPLoadIdColumnName, fieldValue = jobResult.loadId });

                    UpdateListItem(SPSiteURL, SPListName, myItem.id, fieldValueList);
                }
                else
                {
                    List<FieldValue> fieldValueList = new List<FieldValue>();

                    fieldValueList.Add(new FieldValue() { fieldName = SPStatusColumnName, fieldValue = "Missed" });

                    UpdateListItem(SPSiteURL, SPListName, myItem.id, fieldValueList);
                }

                itemCounter += 1;
            }
        }

        //Get all items fro the list
        private static List<MyItem> GetNewItem(string targetSiteUrl, string listName, string filedName)
        {
            List<MyItem> myItemList = new List<MyItem>();

            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(targetSiteUrl))
            {
                context.Credentials = CredentialManager.GetSharePointOnlineCredential(targetSiteUrl);

                Web myWeb = context.Web;
                SP.List myList = myWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

                SP.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = myList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

                context.Load(listItemCollection,
                            eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                                                        item => item,
                                                        item => item["Title"],
                                                        item => item["ID"],
                                                        item => item[filedName]    //Field: "Status"
                                                        )
                            ); 

                // ExecuteQuery will pull all data from SharePoint
                // which has been staged to Load()
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                
                foreach (SP.ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
                {
                    if ((string)listItem[filedName] == "New")
                    {
                        MyItem myItem = new MyItem();

                        myItem.id = (int)listItem["ID"];
                        myItem.title = (string)listItem["Title"];
                        myItem.status = (string)listItem[filedName];

                        myItemList.Add(myItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            return myItemList;

        }
       
        //Update items fields
        static void UpdateListItem(string targetSiteUrl, string listName, int itemId, List<FieldValue> fieldValuesList)
        {

            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(targetSiteUrl))
            {
                context.Credentials = CredentialManager.GetSharePointOnlineCredential(targetSiteUrl);

                //List
                SP.List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

                //List item
                SP.ListItem listItem = announcementsList.GetItemById(itemId);

                foreach (FieldValue fieldValue in fieldValuesList)
                {
                    //Change field value
                    listItem[fieldValue.fieldName] = fieldValue.fieldValue;
                }
                
                listItem.Update();

                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }

        private class MyItem
        {
            public int id;
            public string title;
            public string status;
        }

        private class FieldValue
        {
            public string fieldName;
            public string fieldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Job step settings look like:
[CMD step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULQVB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I doesn't use access token to enter the site. The application works fine in Visual Studio because previously received access token was kept in the cache. I've rewrite this part using example from here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-csom-for-net-standard/

Answer (score 0):

When VS is used it uses normally the build-in webserver as fa as I can remember - deploying to a real IIS may end in trouble. Please have a look here

https://en.it1352.com/article/530a9f2f660b4088a9637b7d294194af.html

Anyway - in some cases TLS missing for authentication cause trouble

Comment: Hi devnull 

Thanks for the article. It describes how to solve then problem using proxy.  In my case I have already set up proxy under my account to execute CMD step with command to run console application. The command line is:
```
"C:\Work\Repose\ETL_LoadDataCSV\SharePointTrigger\bin\Release\ConsoleSharePoint.exe"
```

As for your idea of TLS I should consider this option on more details. Could you please provide me more information about the use of TLS in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the user permission on SQL?
([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-a-user-to-create-and-manage-sql-server-agent-jobs?view=sql-server-ver15) a guide to create and configure an user to use SQL Server Agent Job)

Comment: Hi Piccio95
Sure, I created the credential from my windows account and used it in the step property "Run as"
This account has sysadmin permissions on the SQL Server and also has an administration permissions on the OS.